# Get total sales grouped by customer and product

Tags: python

I have a list of sales:

```py
items = [
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 10},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'B', 'count': 15},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'C', 'count': 100},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 50},
]
```

I want to find the total sales of each product to every customer, like this:

```py
items = [
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 60},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'B', 'count': 15},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'C', 'count': 100},
]
```

In the result, see that product A customer A has a `count` that's the sum of the counts of product A customer A in the input.

This is what I did:

```py
rs = []
for item in items:
  has = False
  for item1 in rs:
    if item1['product'] == item['product'] and \
      item1['customer'] == item['customer']:
      item1['count'] += item['count']
      has = True
      break
  if not has:
    rs.append(item)
```

While this works, I think it might be over-complex.  Can it be made simpler and clearer?

Comment: I know you were redirected here from Stack Overflow, to improve your question you should probably read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Comment: 'aggregate' doesn't really describe what you're trying to do, it could mean anything. "Aggregate list of dicts by summing counts for each {product,customer} combination" does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you follow the PEP-8 recommendation to use four spaces per indent level, as that makes your code more readable by other Python programmers.

Instead of the bare code, we should create a function, that we can call (perhaps in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block).

Instead of the linear search, we could simply use a `collections.Counter` for counting.  First we need to transform so that the key is product+customer:

```
d = Counter()
for item in items:
    key = (item['product'],item['customer'])
    d[key] += item['count']
```

Then we need to transform back to the list of dictionaries:

```
[ {'product': p, 'customer': c, 'count': v} for (p, c), v in d.items() ]
```

---

Modified code:

```
from collections import Counter

def aggregate(items):
    d = Counter()
    for item in items:
        key = (item['product'],item['customer'])
        d[key] += item['count']
    return [ {'product': p, 'customer': c, 'count': v}
             for (p, c), v in d.items() ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = [
        {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 10},
        {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'B', 'count': 15},
        {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'C', 'count': 100},
        {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 50},
    ]

    print(aggregate(items))
```

Comment: Well, using `Counter` kind of sidesteps the point where the OP doesn't want to use libraries. If the only restriction is that there be no import statements, the best option would indeed be to roll the OP's own version of `Counter` with a `dict`.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is a part of the Python standard library.  There's no good reason not to use the facilities provided!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you @TobySpeight!

Comment: `collections.Counter` is a library, it's a builtin one. OP, you mean "only using builtin libraries".

Comment: Creating new Counters for every single item doesn't sound right.
Instead you can just increase the existing counter: `d[key] += item['count']`

Comment: @Jakube, you're right, and I think I started with something like that before experimenting to see if I could use a comprehension to construct the counter.  I don't know why I didn't go back to that!  Edited appropriately.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably unpack the key tuple into variables as well in the dictionary comprehension, something like `[{"product": p, "customer": c, "count": v} for (p, c), v in d.items()]`. This avoids the use of intransparent tuple indices.

Comment: Thanks @Schmuddi - I've implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I get the below output without using any libraries? (in a shorter way)

#### Without using any libraries?

Vocabulary like "libraries" is often used ambiguously.
Do you mean "without `import`ing anything, or "without *installing*" anything?

If your goal is to only use modules in the Python Standard Library, there are *lots* of ways of doing this; [Toby Speight's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283170/200133) is one, and you might also consider `defaultdict`, `functools.reduce`, etc.

On the other hand, if your goal is to only use "built-ins", stuff that's always in scope in any new python environment, then you're well into the realm of contrived classroom exercises.

#### in a shorter way?

Making brevity a goal in itself is frowned upon; it's making extra work for yourself and everyone around you.
That said, making verbose code more concise will often make it *clearer*, which is certainly worth striving for.
The thing I "dislike" about your existing implementation is not that it's long (it's not especially), it's that I have to read it carefully to understand what it's *for* or *how* it works.

#### So what would I suggest?

If this is a classroom exerciese, then likely you haven't been taught comprehensions. But they're one of the nicer things about python, so I suggest learning them.
The following is reasonably efficient; it makes <s>two</s> three linear passes through the input.
I would really like to write it in a way where all variables are initialized to their final values, but I think doing that in any obvious way would put the complexity back up to quadratic.

```py
sums = {(item['product'], item['customer']): 0  # will update sums next!
        for item in items}
for item in items:
  sums[(item['product'], item['customer'])] += item['count']
rs = [{'product': k[0], 'customer': k[1], 'count': v}
      for k, v in sums.items()]
```

As a final note, regular structures of string-based dictionaries are a big red flag to me, but this probably isn't a context where it makes sense to find a better pattern :)

Comment: You're a very good teacher. I learned a lot. Could you tell me more about this "regular structures of string-based dictionaries are a big red flag to me" or can I read it somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: @NavyFlame not the OP, but: I'd think once you have such a structure being used, maybe it might be time to make it a proper class, with methods that reflect how you use it.

Comment: +1 to muru. Yes, the preferred alternative is usually a class. Because all the string keys are written literally in the code, you can just replace all the dict lookups with class instance attributes. For tidy flat data structures like this, `dataclasses` are quick and easy.

Answer (score 5):

You now have solutions using `collections.Counter` (perhaps the easiest way) and using one's own dictionary. I would like to propose an alternative that uses no dictionary at all.

Finding "duplicates" in a list has quadratic complexity when doing nested loops, however it can be done in linear time if the list is sorted, and sorting the list is itself only O(n log n).

Thus a simple procedural solution to the problem is:

```py
def aggregate(items):
    items.sort(key = lambda item: (item['product'], item['customer']))

    result = []

    for item in items:
        if len(result) > 0 and result[-1]['product'] == item['product'] and result[-1]['customer'] == item['customer']:
           result[-1]['count'] += item['count']
           continue

        result.append({
           'product': item['product'],
           'customer': item['customer'],
           'count': item['count']
        })

    return result
```

This solution has O(n log n) time complexity, and O(n-distinct) extra space complexity.

Comment: Note: more advanced Python users may actually transform `aggregate` into a generator, in which case the solution would have O(1) extra space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Python's itertools has [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if importing that is ok.

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 10},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'B', 'count': 15},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'C', 'count': 100},
  {'product': 'A', 'customer': 'A', 'count': 50},
]

items.sort(key=lambda i: (i['product'], i['customer']))

out = [
    {**k, 'count': sum(i['count'] for i in g)}
    for k, g in groupby(items, lambda i: dict(i,count=0))
    ]
print(out)
```

Groupby creates subiterators for each group and the group changes whenever the value of the key function changes, so if you don't sort beforehand, the groups don't work as expected.

```
dict(i,count=0)  # creates a copy with count zero, making the groups work
```

This was less straighforward than I thought it would be. The mandatory sorting just seems like it should be built in.

Comment: If sorting were built into `itertools.groupby()`, it would need to store the whole input in memory, which is very much against the principles of `itertools`.  I think that's why it requires that its input is already suitably ordered instead.